# vim using leader together with <C-?>

Tags: vim

I found this snippet from [unite.vim](http://www.codeography.com/2013/06/17/replacing-all-the-things-with-unite-vim.html)

```
nnoremap <leader>t :<C-r>Unite -no-split -buffer-name=files   -start-insert file_rec<cr>
```

It seems it try to map "\t" to "Unite -no-split -buffer-name=files   -start-insert file_rec"

what does `<C-r>` mean here ? what is the difference from the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :Unite -no-split -buffer-name=files   -start-insert file_rec<cr>
```

Comment: These are all typos. It should be `<C-U>`, which deletes automatically inserted ranges, see the example at [`:h omap-info`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#omap-info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Ex** mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (written `<C-r>` in Vim) will insert the content of the specified *register* on the Ex command line. `<C-r>U` will insert the content of the `U` register. All commands starting with `:` are **Ex** mode commands.

To see this in action, do the following:

1. Delete a word using `"adw`. This means "delete a word to register `a`".
2. Enter normal mode.
3. Type in `:<C-r>a`. Your **Ex** mode command line will now contain the word.

I have looked at the relevant `.vimrc` and the `unite.vim` source, and I doubt the `<C-r>` is supposed to be there. It is most likely a bug or a typo.

For more information, see `:help c_CTRL-R`.